# How to implement "Utilize SSL / TLS Session identifier" session fixation solution in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, ssl, https

I am looking at different solutions available for session fixation at this web
site http://hungred.com/useful-information/solutions-session-attacks/.

One of the solution is "Utilize SSL / TLS Session identifier". I have few questions related this.

What actually is this mean? 
How we can implement this solution in asp.net? 
Is there any need of coding to implement it or it will be done through by some configuration?

Regarding this solution its also written that "many web development languages do not provide robust built-in functionality for this solution".

So my another question is this that is this functionality built-in for ASP.NET?

Answer (score 0):

Basically, if you use SSL offloading, the appliance (e.g. F5 BIG IP) can add a session cookie based on the client certificate.

In the pure .net when connecting directly to your code this is not possible; however, you can use the client certificate as the identifier itself, so you wouldn't need a cookie.

Stealing a certificate is typically harder than stealing a cookie as private keys are protected by the OS.

Comment: How i can generate SSL/TSL Session Id? How it looks like mean asp session id structure created using Alpahabets A-Z and numbers from 0-5. Is ssl Session Id looks like same or something different?

Comment: @Atif this will largely depend on your appliance. Are you writing your own reverse proxy?